# Computer will not recognize second display upon waking up

Tags: windows, video, drivers, multiple-monitors

One of my user's desktops will not recognize its second display when it wakes up. This problem started this morning, following the installation of several Microsoft Office updates. I can list them if need be, but I don't know how pertinent it is. The desktop will recognize the second monitor once the DVI cable is disconnected and reconnected.

The PC is a Dell Optiplex 360 running Windows Vista Business x64; 2.93GHz Core 2 Duo, 4GB RAM. The video card is an Nvidia GeForce 9300 GE. The primary display is a Dell G2210 connected via DVI, and the secondary display is an Acer x223W also connected via DVI.

The user experienced this problem once several weeks ago. It was solved by updating the video driver. Updating, disabling/enabling, and uninstalling/reinstalling the video driver has not worked in this case.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching it out with a different monitor (or even monitor cable) and see if it still happens. I've experienced problematic monitors that would do this before.

Comment: It was the monitor cable that did it.

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it resolved. Thanks for the update.

Comment: +1 I was having exactly the same problem on the Dell Optiplex 960 (though with an ATI Radeon HD 3470) - switching the display port -> DVI adapter fixed it for me.